# Comparing two Hexadecimal values in C++

Tags: c++

I want to compare two hexadecimal(stored in long) 
below is my code

```
long constant = 80040e14;
if(constant == 80040e14)
    cout<<"Success"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"Fail!!"<<endl;
```

In this code flow control always returns to else part, can anyone please suggest how to proceed with the comparison.

Thanks

Santhosha K

Comment: @Binary Worrier: It compiles only with `e` character (as it is taken as exponent). For every other hex character its a compiler error.

Comment: Those numbers aren't integers. They are doubles. Try doing same thing with BAADF00D or DEADBEEF and see what happens.

Comment: @Naveen: Of course! I may once have know you could that, but if I did it was close on 20 years ago and has since been driven out by something more important, possibly my wifes name :) Thanks mate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prefix your constants with '0x'.

Your constant only has 'e' in it and the compiler will treat numbers of the form: NNNeEEE as scientific notation. Using the '0x' prefix tells the compiler that the following characters are in hexadecimal notation.

In your code, 80040e14 is 8004000000000000000 which is way too big to fit into 32bit value but can fit into a 64bit value. But, 80040e14 is a floating point number so the comparison will convert the long to a float to make it the same type as the constant and so the two values will be different due to the complexities of floating point code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put 0x in front of your hexadecimal numbers in C++

Answer (score 2):

For hexadecimal values you need to prefix the constant with `0x` Otherwise `e` is taken as an exponent and the value is interpreted as a huge *decimal* value. In your cases, most probably this value can not be stored in a long and it overflows. Because of this overflow, your comparison check fails.

Answer (score 1):

To compare two values use the == operator.
The only thing to consider is telling the compiler which base is the value using:

- Decimal: write the number as always you do in "real life". Example: 1 (one), 2 (two), 3 (three), ...
- Hexadecimal: You must append 0x to the value. Example: 0x01 (one), 0x02 (two), 0x03 (three), ...
- Binary: Append 0b. Example: 0b01 (one), 0xb10 (two), 0b11 (three). **Edit:** seems like this isn't true. Don't trust in this feature.

In your example, just do:

```
long constant = 0x80040e14;
if(constant == 0x80040e14L)
    cout<<"Success"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"Fail!!"<<endl;
```

Comment: C++ does not have a binary format for literals. An '0x' prefix indicates hexadecimal, a '0' prefix denotes an octal number. '0b01' and '0b11' would both generate compiler errors ('b' is an invalid octal character) and '0xb10' is 2832 in decimal.

Comment: Oops, that's a feature I only used in C, I wrongly assumed C++ inherited it.

Comment: It's not C either (possibly a compiler extension)

Comment: Maybe, I used it in a compiler for an embedded system. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to compare a hex?
Use `0x80040e14` -> notice the `0x` prefix to let the compiler know it is hexadecimal format.

The way you write it the compiler may try to parse it as a float (e meaning exponential), but I did not actually try it to see how it handles this.

Comment: Gnu g++ 4.4.3 gives this warning: "overflow in implicit constant conversion"

Answer (score 0):

80040e14 is a double. When assigned to a long it becomes zero. 80040e14L is a long double.
the expression

```
constant == 80040e14L
```

promotes constant to a long double so you have

```
0.0 == 80040e14
```